# recent media instagram GET request returns status 200 but empty data

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, xamarin.ios, xamarin.auth

I am doing a simple GET request using this instagram API endpoint:  `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USER ID}/media/recent?access_token={ACCESS TOKEN}` 
I get the access token via OAuth2Authenticator from Xamarin.Auth plugin.
I just notice today that the get recent media request is returning this :

```
{
"pagination": {},
"data": [],
"meta": {
    "code": 200
}
```

PS: I am testing with my admin instagram account, and also with approved sandbox users. 
Scope : basic

Comment: Does the user info API return valid info for that access token? (`.../v1/users/self/?access_token=XXXX`)

Comment: Having the same problem all of sudden today.

Comment: same here. seems to happen only with private instagram accounts

Comment: @SushiHangover yes as I mentioned before, I am using the correct token generated after the auth.
@p

Comment: plankguy
@ChristopherBlum If you delete the cookies of your browser do the auth request again and after that test the endpoint url in the same browser it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is really basic.
If you are in the sandbox mode then you will need to switch your account privacy to public in Instagram. Private accounts are not working properly for me.
[image]

Comment: That does work, however private accounts were working as of May 14th 2018. Is this a recent change?

Comment: @plankguy I have no idea.
My request for a basic permission is pending since 5 days now...